# Jenkins Custom Email Generation

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have been using *Jenkins* as my automation server for the last couple of weeks. So far so good.

Now I need to generate notification upon build completion. I am using the *Email-ext plugin* for this.

However, I need to add some custom content into the email content. So far I was using the default ${DEFAULT_CONTENT}. Is there an easy way to append some custom content from a file.

Looks like I need to extend the groovy-text template. However I am willing to know whether is there an easy way to append text from a file easily.

Comment: Do you got a solution Because I do stuck here

Answer (score -2):

The [documentation for the Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) says that you can add a script to customize the contents of the email in the advanced configuration section of the plugin. There should be a button/link to expand the advanced options in the build configuration next to the plugin's section:

> To see the advanced configuration for the plugin, first click on Override Global setting checkbox, then click the "Advanced" button.  This section allows you to specify recipients for each type of email trigger as well as a pre-send script that can be used to modify the email just prior to sending.

Comment: From Advance section we can include report in email body. I am facing same issue, pre-send script send attachment in email . How to include text along with this report body